# Braces in shell parameter expansion don't work right

Tags: bash

I have a program parsing two files and comparing them looking for conflicts between the two and allowing the user to decide what action to take. As a result, I need to be able to parse the lines below. If a string contains `{` or `}` when using pattern replacement parameter expansion it will cause an error.

I was looking for a potential work around for the following lines

```
F=TSM_CLASS="Test text {class}"
newstring=${F//{class}/\\{class\\}}
```

Results:

```
echo $newstring
TSM_CLASS="Test text }/\{class\}}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${F//{class}` is a complete parameter expansion which replaces every instance of `{class` in `F`'s value with empty string. To embed braces in the pattern and/or the replacement string, you need to quote them.

```
$ F=TSM_CLASS="Test text {class}"
$
$ echo "${F//{class\}/\\{class\\\}}"
TSM_CLASS=Test text \{class\}
```